# Need a program for using shortcut keys to switch between specific programs

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

Open programs:

- Chrome
- Dreamweaver
- Photoshop

Requirements:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Focus Chrome window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Focus Dreamweaver window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Focus Photoshop window

I need a solution for this...

Comment: what should happen to key-strokes/shortcuts that already use those combinations? eg Ctrl-P is 'Print' mostly, and Ctrl-C for Chrome will break more than it fixes. Alt-<key> keystrokes get used by menus and widgets on screen.  Alt-tab (and Alt-Shift-Tab) is the easiest way to do this stuff.

Comment: I want to go directly to a specific program :/

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: I'm useing Windows 8

Comment: AutoHotkey is prefect for me... Thenk you Karan :)... if do u you want add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com) script that employs [*WinActivate*](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm):

```
!c::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Chrome 
{
    WinActivate 
    return
}
!d::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Dreamweaver 
{
    WinActivate 
    return
}
!p::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Photoshop 
{
    WinActivate 
    return
}
```

Comment: Good answer. In addition you have the option of adding an else statement to each IF statement to open the program if it isn't open already.

Comment: @Jikag: Yes, if that's required then [Run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) can be used with an ELSE added to each IF. Of course, besides the above just as in Win7 in Win8 too Windows Key+Number Key (1-9) will switch to desktop mode and make the Nth application on the taskbar active (where 1 is the leftmost). Obviously different apps will occupy different slots each time based on their order of execution though, whereas the script above won't be affected by this.

Comment: Another good point, though if you want to make the programs occupy the same position every time, you can open a program, right click on it and choose "pin to taskbar"

Comment: @Jikag: Ah yes, forgot about pinned shortcuts retaining their positions!